# How could I make OptionMenu for 10 options with the same choices using a for loop and get the values using Tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, optionmenu

This is what I have tried so far:

```
choices = ['True', 'False']
self.dd = StringVar()
for i in range(k):
OptionMenu(root, self.dd, *choices).grid(row=i+6, column=2, sticky=W)
```

When I make a choice for one option, that choice is selected for all options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `OptionMenu` needs its own instance of `StringVar`

```
self.vars = []
for i in range(k):
    var = StringVar()
    OptionMenu(root, var, *choices)
    self.vars.append(var)
```